# Ranking data in excel without skipping ranks

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dataset of over 5000 line items. I need to calculate ranks based on various parameters. Currently I'm using the formula for ranking `{=SUM(IFERROR(1/COUNTIF(H$5:H$194,IF(H$5:H$194<H5,H$5:H$194)),0))+1}`

However, due to large dataset size, it is very inefficient and is taking hours to run. Can anyone suggest any alternate code for this?

Example:

If scores are given, I want the rank as displayed in Rank Column

`Score    Rank
  88       9
   7       2
  45       6
  23       5
   2       1
  56       7
   7       2
  98      10
  12       3
  45       6
  23       5
  56       7
  86       8
  19       4`

Comment: Is the `Rank()` function inappropriate for some reason ? A 3 sec. search on "excel rank data" allows you to find it. And generally built-in functions are much faster than reinvented ones.

Comment: @iDevlop is right. You could be using RANK(). If you are using multiple criteria, you could create a column for each criteria ranking and sort by the different rankings. If you want to combine the criteria, use a nested rank like RANK(RANK(1)+RANK(2)+RANK(3)) or RANK(.5*RANK(1)+.3*RANK(2)+.2*RANK(3)) to weight them.

Comment: Also important to note, while using `RANK`. Instead of running for each value individually where Excel will have to internally sort the data for each function call, it may be called as an Array function causing only one sorting and hence much faster results for large arrays

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put the entire table into a PivotTable, and then keep pivottable sorted by value, with a serial number column next to it. Then run a

```
=VLOOKUP(...)
```

on the Pivottable values and pull-in the column of serial number for rank.

A bit convoluted but better than waiting for hours.